# Embedding generic sql queries into c# program

Tags: c#, mysql

Okay referring to my first question code in the main, I want the user to enter employee name at runtime and then i take this name which user has entered and compare it with the e_name of my emp table , if it exists i want to display all information of that employee , how can I achieve this ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConnectCsharppToMySQL
{
    public  class DBConnect
    {
        private MySqlConnection connection;
        private string server;
        private string database;
        private string uid;
        private string password;

        string name;

        //Constructor
        public DBConnect()
        {
            Initialize();
        }

        //Initialize values
        private void Initialize()
        {
            server = "localhost";
            database = "test";
            uid = "root";
            password = "";
            string connectionString;
            connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" +
            database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
        }

        //open connection to database
        private bool OpenConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                //When handling errors, you can your application's response based 
                //on the error number.
                //The two most common error numbers when connecting are as follows:
                //0: Cannot connect to server.
                //1045: Invalid user name and/or password.
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 0:
                        MessageBox.Show("Cannot connect to server.  Contact administrator");
                        break;

                    case 1045:
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid username/password, please try again");
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Close connection
        private bool CloseConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Close();
                return true;
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }

        //Insert statement
        public void Insert()
        {
            string query = "INSERT INTO emp (e_name, age) VALUES('Pooja R', '21')";

            //open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create command and assign the query and connection from the constructor
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

                //Execute command
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }

        //Update statement
        public void Update()
        {
            string query = "UPDATE emp SET e_name='Peachy', age='22' WHERE e_name='Pooja R'";

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //create mysql command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                //Assign the query using CommandText
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                //Assign the connection using Connection
                cmd.Connection = connection;

                //Execute query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                //close connection
                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }    

        //Select statement
        public List<string>[] Select()
        {

            string query = "SELECT * FROM emp where e_name=(/*I WANT USER ENTERED NAME TO GET INSERTED HERE*/)";


            //Create a list to store the result
            List<string>[] list = new List<string>[3];
            list[0] = new List<string>();
            list[1] = new List<string>();
            list[2] = new List<string>();

            //Open connection
            if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
            {
                //Create Command
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
                //Create a data reader and Execute the command
                MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //Read the data and store them in the list
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    list[0].Add(dataReader["e_id"] + "");
                    list[1].Add(dataReader["e_name"] + "");
                    list[2].Add(dataReader["age"] + "");
                }

                //close Data Reader
                dataReader.Close();

                //close Connection
                this.CloseConnection();

                //return list to be displayed
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                return list;
            }
        }


        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {

            DBConnect db1 = new DBConnect();
            Console.WriteLine("Initializing"); 
            db1.Initialize();

             Console.WriteLine("Search :");
             Console.WriteLine("Enter the employee name");
             db1.name = Console.ReadLine();
             db1.Select();

                      Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: a emp table in a database test , has e_name,e_id,age columns. I want user to enter an employee name at runtime and as he enters the name , he should be able to see all the details of that employee. i want to know how can i achieve this ? like referencing values

Comment: I'd suggest a tutorial site, this is abot as basic as it gets in terms of db interaction.

Answer (score 0):

use MySqlParameter as :

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand ("SELECT * FROM emp where e_name =@Name", connection))
    {
        //
        // Add new SqlParameter to the command.
        //
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name);// name is get from console read line. 

        //
        // Read in the SELECT results.
        //
        MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // read each value 
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT

here are the changes you need to do

```
//add name as Select method parameter
public List<string>[] Select(string name)
{
  string query = "SELECT * FROM emp where e_name =@Name"; // change your select query 

  ....

  MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", name) // add this line after creating command 

  ....
}
```

call above method as

```
 db1.name = Console.ReadLine();
 db1.Select(db1.name);
```

Comment: how do i implement your above code ? like where to add and how to invoke ?

Comment: on running the program i dont get any window as the output printing the statements written in the main

Answer (score 0):

This method will need to accept a parameter:

```
public List<string>[] Select()
```

Something like this, most likely:

```
public List<string>[] Select(string name)
```

Then, within that method, you can reference the `name` variable.  When calling that method, you would supply that variable:

```
var listOfResults = dbConnectInstance.Select(someNameValue);
```

Once that variable is in your method, you can use it in your SQL query.  You would do this by setting it as a parameter in your `SELECT` query.  Something like this, perhaps (keep in mind this is free-hand code, I don't have the MySql .NET library handy to test):

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM emp where e_name=@ename";
//... (opening the connection like you do now, etc.)
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@ename", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 80).Value = name;
//... (continuing as you do now)
```

What this essentially does is create a placeholder in the query called `@ename` (it can be called anything, the `@` is the important part for being a placeholder) which expects to be replaced with an actual value.  Adding an item to the `Parameters` collection on the command object is what replaces the placeholder with the value.

This is called "parameterized queries" in ADO.NET (which is the database connection technology you're using).  It helps keep your queries dynamic (one query can be re-used with different values) as well as helps prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdb58b2f.aspx) (note that I said *helps prevent*, as it's not a magic bullet and increased understanding of the subject in general is your best defense).

More information specifically about the MySql .NET library's queries and parameters can be found [starting here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-net-examples-mysqlparameter.html).